# jQuery ajax .done not calling with Sinatra JSON response

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, json, sinatra

I'm getting back into stuff with a simple Sinatra project, but I'm having a small problem with getting a jQuery .done() block to execute.

The background:
- Local development machine (for now) - Mac OS X mavericks
- Apache/mysql/PHP stack running & listening on 80, 8888
- sinatra running on 3000

The handler in Sinatra has been stripped to the bare minimum:

```
post '/' do 
    status 200
    content_type :json
    params.to_json
end
```

The form submitted:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/ph/api" method="post" id="apitest">
    <input type="hidden" name="recipes[]" value="cornbread"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="recipes[]" value="taters"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="recipes[]" value="PO-TAY-TOES"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

The AJAX with jQuery (1.10, google hosted):

```
$('#apitest').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var myreq = $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"http://localhost:3000/",
        dataType:"text",
        data:$('#apitest').serialize()
    });
    myreq.done(function() {
        alert("done");
    });
    myreq.always(function() {
        alert("always");
    });
});
```

When I click, the form submits. Looking at the traffic in charles, everything looks legit.

Here's the request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/apitest.html
Content-Length: 70
Origin: http://localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

recipes%5B%5D=cornbread&recipes%5B%5D=taters&recipes%5B%5D=PO-TAY-TOES
```

Here's the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 48
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Connection: keep-alive
Server: thin 1.6.1 codename Death Proof

{"recipes":["cornbread","taters","PO-TAY-TOES"]}
```

As expected at the end, my "always" handler fires. "done" never seems to fire. I expect there's something here with security (same origin?) that's eluding me, but I've been looking at this problem for long enough that I'm fried or missing something screamingly obvious.

Thanks much for any insight or tips that can be provided!

a fail() block added as follows:

```
myreq.fail(function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.log(xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText);
});
```

Output from console:

```
0 - error
```

Status & err give nothing and "error" respectively.

Comment: Try adding a fail handler and see if that fires, and with what errors.

Comment: Fail gives me a status of 0 and a message of "error", and looking at the object a responseText of "" as well.

Comment: Does it still fail with the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: Using jQuery 1.10.2. Can't use 2.x because IE8 support is unfortunately required.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a json

```
var myreq = $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost:3000/",
    dataType:"json", 
    data:{"vl":$('#apitest').serialize()}
});

myreq.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
   alert("done");
});

// callback handler that will be called on failure
myreq.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     alert("errors"+textStatus);
});

myreq.always(function() {
    alert("always");
}); 



provided http://localhost:3000/ should return a valid json back.
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, handling this via direct AJAX was a mess - never did figure out what was happening. Using a crude intermediary on the server made everything work happily.